# Highcharts exporting className

Tags: highcharts, export, classname

How do you set a classname for an exported graph in Highcharts? I tried this but it did not work:

```
exporting: {
   chartOptions: {
   chart: {
      className: 'negPos'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your goal of adding class.adding class at export is not working http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/1s0h3wng/

Comment: I am using styled mode and would like to override the colors of the column in my CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/1s0h3wng/1/ check this

Comment: I was able to apply one color but I need the positive amounts to be green and negative red. I previously had used a classname to apply this rule

Comment: can you add screenshot of your requirement

Comment: You need to send those csv resources to the exporting server - see the answer and example from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340707/highcharts-css-styles-when-exporting

Comment: this is my chart. when exported, it shows blue bars http://jsfiddle.net/er1187/tfs0qv0a/ @Deep3015

Comment: @ellier7 is this acceptable http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/n7L6q4v4/1/

Comment: that does the trick, thanks so much! @Deep3015 you can promote your comment to an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[negativeColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.negativeColor) add to plot options

```js
Highcharts.chart(container, {
  chart: {
    //className: 'negPos',
    type: 'column',
    spacingBottom: 20,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
      fontSize: '11px',
      fontWeight: 'lighter'
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts',
    align: 'center',
    style: {
      fontSize: '15px',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 'lighter'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: '%'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
      fontSize: '11px',
      align: 'center'
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.x + ': </b><br>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + '%'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      negativeColor: '#d9534f',
      threshold: 0,
    }
  },
  /* plotOptions: {
       bar: {
           dataLabels: {
               enabled: false
           }
       }
   },*/
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
    shadow: true
  },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    color: '#5cb85c',
    data: [54, 21, -3, 18, 5, -11]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```