# HighChart - How to apply override Subtitle style css in HighChart Print

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I was required to bring **HighChart SubTitle** to **Left** align, so I've overridden the style using the below code in my chart

```
.highcharts-subtitle{
            left: 100px !important;
        }
```

I am able to see this change in the chart view but when I export the SubTitle it's back to being center aligned.

[JSFiddle link:](http://jsfiddle.net/m052y9ud/15/)

**Chart View:**

[image]

**Export View:**

[image]

How to export SubTitle with left align.

Comment: you can updated subtitle as http://jsfiddle.net/vhrtf25j/  check https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle.align

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should position the subtitle element by **x** property:

```
subtitle: {
  useHTML: true,
  align: 'left',
  text: 'SubTitle: line1 <br/> SubTitle: line2 ',
  x: 100
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u4qpod2a/

You can also look at this topic: [Highcharts css styles when exporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340707/highcharts-css-styles-when-exporting), to find out how to export chart with css styles.